# Setting environment variables on a jsch ChannelExec

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I want to run a remote command in a `ChannelExec` (not `ChannelShell`) in jsch. Apparently no environment variables are loaded, but my command needs them:

```
_channel.setCommand("source /etc/bash.bashrc; source ~/.bashrc; echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH");
_channel.connect();
```

returns nothing, although `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set in my `~/.bashrc`.

```
_channel.setEnv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", "/my/add/path:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH");
_channel.setCommand("echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH");
_channel.connect();
```

does not work either -- still no output of the `echo` command.

Any idea what is wrong? When exactly do I have to call `setEnv`? Before I do the `connect()` or after? And why does the implicit solution via `source` not work?

Comment: Are you really using `_channel.setEnv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH" = "/my/add/path:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH");` ? This looks like a syntax error.

Comment: Paulo: thanks for the hint, it was just a typing error in this entry. My sourcecode is syntactically right.

Comment: Yes, other echo commands work.

Answer (score 3):

For the second way of doing this, I suppose is is normal that this doesn't work. While an SSH client can send any environment variable it wants, it's the decision of the server which of these are passed to the target process, and which are simply ignored. Often servers are configured to allow only `LC_*`, `TERM` and similar variables. For OpenSSH sshd, you can configure this in [`sshd_config`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd_config&sektion=5) with the option `AcceptEnv`.  (On current Ubuntu Systems, the default is `AcceptEnv LANG LC_*`.)

Also, passing a `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the value of the variable will not work, as the server will most likely not interpret the value as a shell expression.

For the first way, I have no idea why this doesn't work. Maybe your bashrc scripts have some programming in them to immediately exit if not in interactive mode, or if not connected to a terminal?  A complete reproducible example might help here.

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround now, but this is not a solution. My guess is, that `setEnv()` is buggy, either in JSch or in Open SSH server.

The workaround:

```
_channel.setCommand("export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\"foo\" && echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH");
```

Comment: As I said in my answer, I think this is intentional. Have a look at the `AcceptEnv` option in [sshd_config](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd_config&sektion=5).

Comment: The command accepts any list of command: Then the workaround can be written with a sequential list of command (ie with a semicolon in place of the AND && control operator) such as _channel.setCommand("export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\"foo\";  echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH");

Answer (score 0):

Setting *Acceptenv* to the name or pattern of the environment variable to be inherited worked for me. The file is at /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

The RFC for using the setEnv mentions that the server settings must approve the setting of environment variables.

```
AcceptEnv PATH
AcceptENV ORA*
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the SSH RFC, the TERM variable is set when initializing the SSH connection. This is set initially, regardless of AcceptEnv.
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4254#section-6.2

Like others said in order to call _channel.setEnv(), you need to change your AcceptEnv.
Jcraft by default sends vt100.

in RequestPtyReq.java:

```
   class RequestPtyReq extends Request{
      private String ttype="vt100";
      private int tcol=80;
      private int trow=24;
      private int twp=640;
      private int thp=480;
```

Comment: I don't understand what have the TERM to do with the settings of environment variable ? Can you explain in details ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
_channel.setCommand("echo \\$LD_LIBRARY_PATH");
```

**NOTE** the "double back slash" (\\) before the "Dollar" ($) sign.